# ReflectionException in activerecords codeigniter

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I tried looking for a solution online, i triple checked if there where any spelling mistakes or if my database had an incorrect value, i got the same error before and deleted the file and now i have the same error on another file that worked perfectly yesterday. Any help would be appreciated

[Wed Jan 21 11:25:56 2015] [warn] [client 213.127.155.226] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class \SubscriptionHasType does not exist' in /var/www/vhosts/boris3.pro1.nl/httpdocs/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.3/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Reflections.php:33, referer:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer you can't use plural(putting an s at the end of the name) when making model names because it searches for the non plural form